# Spry Menu Bars in IE

Tags: dreamweaver, menubar, spry

I'm kind of new to the web design realm and currently using Dreamweaver CS6. I created a website that uses spry menu bars and it looks fine on Firefox but once I try to open the webpage on IE the bar has a white background and when hovering over the options the submenus are being displayed on the left. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I'm pretty sure it has to do with with Spry CSS but I don't know where to start.

Here's a link to the website: [www.sunmachinery.com](http://www.sunmachinery.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check on `line 230` of the `SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css`, that's where the background is set to white for IE.

As far as the submenus poping up on the left, I'm guessing you may have deleted some css somewhere that was telling IE that the dropdowns were supposed to be relative to the menu items. I would try getting a fresh unedited version of `SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css` and see if IE renders them in the correct place, then step by step redo each edit until you find which one broke it in IE.